# Placing Google Map iFRAM to center of page in HTLM table row

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe, html-table

i am using angular.js and putting ifram in my table row of html, its not appearing in the center of page.
[image]

i am using this code

```
 <tr>
        <td>
         
         <iframe id="myIframe"
            [src]="'https://maps.google.com/maps?q='+rfq.latitude+','+rfq.longitude+'&hl=es;z=18&amp;output=embed' | safe"
            width="100%" 
            height="450" 
            frameborder="0"
       ></iframe>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

how can i place this map to center of page with full weight

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to add css in angular but you can simply use this `position: absolute` to center the iframe.

you can also remove `height` and `width` from `iframe` 
Edited code

I have seen your code, what you were doing wrong that you were adding `width` and `height` and other css properties ouside the `style` tag. If you look at my code you'll understand.

```html
<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d30704255.110777132!2d64.3828365886956!3d20.047174681973626!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x30635ff06b92b791%3A0xd78c4fa1854213a6!2sIndia!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1604400347555!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; position: absolute; height: 300px;left: 50%;top: 50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%)"  allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" ></iframe>
```

[Here's the link of codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-surf-tv0dh?file=/src/index.html)

Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: its not work
 <iframe id="myIframe"
                [src]="'https://maps.google.com/maps?q='+rfq.latitude+','+rfq.longitude+'&hl=es;z=18&amp;output=embed' | safe"
                frameborder="0"
                width="100%"
                height="200px"
                position="absolute"
                top="50%"
                left="50%"
                transform="translate(-50%,-50%)"
                style="border:0" 
                allowfullscreen="" 
                aria-hidden="false" 
                tabindex="0"
           ></iframe>

Comment: can i ask how you are embedding google maps to your page?? and did you tried adding css to iframe tag? and last.. do you have any experience with front dev? thanks

Comment: i am using this code
<iframe id="myIframe" [src]="'maps.google.com/…' | safe" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="200px" position="absolute" top="50%" left="50%" transform="translate(-50%,-50%)" style="border:0" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" ></iframe>
i dnt have much experience on front end dev
i am backend, mobile, apps and web app developer

Comment: @ShoaibAnwar sorry I don't have any experience in backed but I did solved you problem after some research, take a look at my edited code. Thanks

Comment: Thanks its getting full width but it overriding to my other row on page

https://i.ibb.co/RbrHgyF/Screen-Shot-2020-11-04-at-9-59-33-AM.png

Comment: sorry I don't know about the other elements... But if my code is working for you, don't forget to accept my answer. and yes you can adjust the map by using transform, margin and other css properties.

Comment: @ShoaibAnwar could you please accept my answer if your problem is resolved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224097/discussion-between-jeet-viramgama-and-shoaib-anwar).