# Angular 6 how can apply condition correctly on table row of html

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if, tablerow

I want to show row of table only when my variable value is equal to accepted

```
<tr *ngIf="{{rfq.status}}===Accpeted" >
        <td>Assign To Staff Member</td>
        <td>
          <div>
            
            <select (change)="Selected($event)">
              
              <option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group.id">
                {{group.name}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <input type="button" (click)="getVal()" value="Assign"/>
      </td>
```

What is correct way to do, I want to show row only when `rqf.status === Accepted`, When i am doing with other parameters is working like

```
<tr *ngIf="quotations || quotations.length" >
        <td>Assign To Staff Member</td>
        <td>
          <div>
            
            <select (change)="Selected($event)">
              
              <option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group.id">
                {{group.name}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <input type="button" (click)="getVal()" value="Assign"/>
      </td>
    
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the `{{`, and add single quotes:

```
<tr *ngIf="rfq.status === 'Accepted'">
```

Comment: Done!..Thank you!
Can you answer this question also?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64658705/placing-google-map-ifram-to-center-of-page-in-htlm-table-row/64661384#64661384